# How to convert separate process executed Junit tests to display in the standard way in Idea

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

I am creating a test framework where all the test cases are required to be executed in a separated processor (JVM) and the final results of the sub process will be sent to the parent after execution is completed. Here I am sending a `org.junit.runner.Result` type object to the back to the parent as the result. Of course I can print the object details in the console without an issue.

But I need these results to be printed in the standard output way of idea where you will see when executing a `Junit` test itself. (see the below image)

[image]

How could I convert my results to a standard way where idea (or maybe eclipse) will understand that these are test results and display like the above image ?

PS. I am using Assert.assertEquals(resultSuccess, true) for the final results, but still the output is not displayed in the standard way

Comment: Sounds like you should go about making a customer Junit runner.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you creating a custom runner here?  (And out of genuine curiosity, why do you need separate JVMs?)

Comment: Yes. Its actually a custom runner. This is an automation framework to test a bit of a large desktop application. When the application starts, there are lots of resources are created (e.g. - EJBs created.... etc) So in order to make the test framework independent from the actual application we execute every automation test scenario in separate JVMs. Otherwise if the test scenario fails and if the application explicitly closed, there could be issues due to resource not cleared in the memory. The approach is for execute the test automation independent from the application